# Assign IPv6 subnet to interface - outgoing requests

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6

I received a IPv6 subnet /64 from my provider (vultr). Many people are asking how to assign whole subnet to interface. As far as I understand, the easiest option is `ip addr add 2001:4860:4860:abcd::/64 dev eth0`. This works fine for incoming requests to any ip in subnet. But how can i use them for outgoing request? With this command my outgoing ip is 2001:4860:4860:abcd::, but i want to use any in range, like `2001:4860:4860:abcd:c37:a324:40f3:98fd`.
Is it even possible? Or does this relate directly to the program that makes the requests?

Comment: "_Many people are asking how to assign whole subnet to interface._" Why? Do you do that with IPv4? Remember that IPv6 allows you to use any address in a network, including the zero address, so `ip addr add 2001:4860:4860:abcd::/64 dev eth0` is adding that one address to the interface, not the entire network. That address happens to be the router anycast address. Would assigning `10.11.12.0 255.255.255.0` to the interface add the entire IPv4 network to the interface?

Comment: It looks like I'm completely confused with ipv6. But anyway can i change the address for outgoing request to any from subnet?

Comment: IPv6 addressing is really a lot like IPv4 addressing, except that it is easier to add multiple addresses to an interface. That is because each interface will have, at least, a link-local address, but you can add global or ULA addresses, too, and you can add addresses from different networks to the one interface. Having multiple addresses with the same network really isn't all that useful, except for something like [Privacy Extensions](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4941). There is also [Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724).

Comment: I think many people get confused by IPv6 using only the CIDR notation of the mask length instead of an explicit mask (they are really the same thing). It looks like you are adding an entire network, rather than the single address, and the fact that IPv6 has no broadcast, so you can use every network address, including the network address, makes it seem like you are adding an entire network when it is really a single (zero) address.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to choose "a few" and add them to the interfaces.  The definition of "a few" is up to you.

You would then have your client software choose it's outgoing v6 address (if it supports this) to rotate between the addresses.

Userland software can't pick an IPv6 address out of thin air and use that as the source (using standard socket calls that is).  This is above the userland software's "pay grade" so to speak.  You have to have the address(es) assigned to your NIC at the OS/kernel level.